# Catch OS exception when Javascript calls Perl script

Tags: javascript, perl, exception

I have a Java script (say) a.js that calls a Perl script b.pl by:

JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("http://:/cgi-bin/b.pl");

xmlhttpPost is something like:

```
function xmlhttpPost(strURL)
{
    var xmlHttpReq=createXMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttpReq.open('POST', noCache(strURL), true);
```

where createXMLHttpRequest creates ActiveXObject

b.pl calls another perl module, c.pm. In c.pm, there is a piece of code to catch OS
exception:

```
eval {
    $ftp->put($filenamepath); };
if ($@) {
    return "FTP time-out"; }
```

$ftp leverages Net::FTP.

If I run b.pl from command line and there is a time-out exception when using ftp to put a file, the excpetion was caught correctly. However, if b.pl is run via a.js, the time-out exception was not caught.

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think the exception was not caught?

Comment: createXMLHttpRequest is probably not activex unless you still run IE5 or IE6?

what does noCache() do? add "&random=123456" at the end of the string to make it unique to prevent caching, and does it work properly (try to include alert(noCache(strURL))?

If you only return "FTP time-out", this may be caught as a (malformed) http header. try to return e.g.
    `return "Pragma: no-cache\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n<pre>FTP time-out</pre>"`

Comment: When exception is caught, "FTP time-out" will be returned to b.pl. b.pl basically print whatever returned into a flat file. When I ran b.pl from command line, I saw that "FTP time-out" was printed in the file. On the other hand, when b.pl was invoked via a.js, I don't see the message.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider looking into [CGI::Carp](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI/Carp.html). There appear to be to be several different methods that might interest you in that documentation.

Comment: When the exception is caught, "FTP time-out" will be returned to